# Выполнение bash-скрипта последовательно в цикле

Tags: python, bash

Есть определенный bash-скрипт , который я пытаюсь исполнить через оболочку. Скрипт , который я хочу выполнить выдаёт в терминал численное значение типа (0.00012 или -0.00012). Выполнение скрипта идёт (скрипт + аргумент к нему). ./script.sh -d # Я хочу написать python скрипт , который выполнит этот bash-скрипт 100 раз с аргументами от -d 1 до -d 100. Вот как я пытаюсь сделать сейчас:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import subprocess


n = 1

args = '/,,/,,/,,/,,/script.sh' + ' -d '
argspopen = args + str(n)
cmd = subprocess.Popen(argspopen, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if "0" in line:
        print "domain " + "    : " + line
    if "Error" in line:
        print "Domain don`t work"
```

Этот скрипт только для 1 «домена» под номером 1. Как зациклить это всё и получить вывод типа: domain 10 : 0.00012 и так для всех 100 доменов (если ошибка, то Domain # don`t work) Спасибо.

Comment: Опечатка с запятыми только в примере в вопросе `'/,,/,,/,,/,,/script.sh'`?

Comment: Это я так путь скрыл. В пути нет проблем. Скрипт сам по себе уже работает , я просто не знаю как сделать последовательное выполнение скрипта с параметрами -d #, где # = от 1 до 100

Comment: у вас в скрипте что-то вида списка и `nc -vs hostname port` обертки? перепишите на `socets` для Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте цикл на `n`:

```
import subprocess
import re

args = 'script.sh' + ' -d '
for n in range(1, 101):
    argspopen = args + str(n)
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(argspopen, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in cmd.stdout:
        if not bool(re.search("[A-Za-z]+", line)):
            print "domain " + "{}: ".format(n) + line
        if "Error" in line:
            print "Domain {} don`t work".format(n)
```

Comment: Спасибо. 
А еще вопрос, если можно. Как первый if "0" сделать , чтобы он парсил только значения численные без букв. Т.е. только значения int. Если встречается какая-то буква, то он сразу выдаёт "Domain ...."?

Comment: `import re` и условием регулярного выражения `bool(re.search("[A-Za-z]+", line)` - если есть буквы `True`

Answer (score 0):

Может просто в самой оболочке напрямую без Python?

```
~$ seq 100 | xargs -I% ./script.sh -d %
```

и если скрипт не сложный - стоит переписать на Python, как бы логичнее.